# Insert into query not working

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to get my code to work but its not, i made two forms with update, delete and add buttons to get data out of my database, Vrienden is the table and Voornaam, Achternaam, Omschrijving are the fields. the update and delete buttons work just fine, im having proplems with my add button. can someon help me. code

```
<body>

<?php
include('menu.html');
require('db_connectie.php');

if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE Vrienden SET Voornaam='$_POST[voornaam]', Achternaam='$_POST[achternaam]', Omschrijving='$_POST[omschrijving]' WHERE ID='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $conn);
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Vrienden WHERE ID='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $conn);
}

$voornaam = mysql_escape_string($_POST["addvoornaam"]);
$achternaam = mysql_escape_string($_POST["addachternaam"]);
$omschrijving = mysql_escape_string($_POST["addomschrijving"]);

if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
//$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO Vrienden (Voornaam, Achternaam, Omschrijving) VALUES ('$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$omschrijving')";
//$AddQuery("INSERT INTO Vrienden (Voornaam, Achternaam, Omschrijving) VALUES ('".$_POST['addvoornaam']."', '".$_POST['addvoornaam']."', '".$_POST['addomschrijving']."')");
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO Vrienden (Voornaam, Achternaam, Omschrijving) VALUES ('" . $_POST['addvoornaam'] . "', '" . $_POST['addachternaam'] . "', '" . $_POST['addomschrijving'] . "')";
mysql_query($AddQuery, $conn);
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM Vrienden";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
echo "<table border=0>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Voornaam</th>";
    echo "<th>Achternaam</th>";
    echo "<th>Omschrijving</th>";
echo "</tr>";


while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<form action=friends.php method=post>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . '<input type="text" name="voornaam" value="' . $record['Voornaam'] . '">'.'</td>';
echo '<td>' . '<input type="text" name="achternaam" value="' . $record['Achternaam'] . '">'.'</td>';
echo '<td>' . '<input type="text" name="omschrijving" value="' . $record['Omschrijving'] . '">'.'</td>';
echo "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['ID'] . ">";
echo '<td>' . '<input type=submit name=update value=Wijzigen > </td>';
echo '<td>' . '<input type=submit name=delete value=Verwijderen > </td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</form>';
}
echo '<form action=friends.php method=post';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type=text name= addvoornaam></td>';
echo '<td><input type=text name= addachternaam></td>';
echo '<td><input type=text name= addomschrijving></td>';
echo '<td><input type=submit name=add value=Toevoegen></td>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</table>';


mysql_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my code, the update and delete buttons work fine, but the add one isn't working. ive tried multiple solutions. is it a simple syntax problem im not seeing?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: **Code Full Of Error.** *I'm Shocked To Know That Delete & Update Button Works Fine*

Comment: Use the variables that you set to `mysql_escape_string` in the `INSERT` query, not the original POST variables.

Comment: Give me one minute with this web page and [I will erase your entire database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Also, your database library has been unsupported for 5 years, [and won't even work in the current version of PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Stop using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, as you said "*the update and delete buttons work just fine*". So, I'm not entering into it.

Change here to make your `add` button work too.

Change

```
echo '<form action=friends.php method=post';
```

to

```
echo '<form action=friends.php method=post>';
```

Missing closing `>` in end of `<form>` for `add` button.

```
echo '<form action=friends.php method=post>';
                                          ^Missing Here.
```

**Updated Code.**

```
echo '<form action=friends.php method=post>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type=text name= addvoornaam></td>';
echo '<td><input type=text name= addachternaam></td>';
echo '<td><input type=text name= addomschrijving></td>';
echo '<td><input type=submit name=add value=Toevoegen></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</table>';
```

[**NOTE**: Don't Use `Mysql*` Functions. They Are Deprecated. Use `Mysqli*` Or `Prepared Statement` To Execute Query ]